# Enable Developer Options With Update.zip

Tags: recovery-mode, samsung-galaxy-nexus

Whenever I flash a new ROM I always do the following:

- Enable Developer Options
- Enable Advanced Reboot Menu
- Enable Root access Apps and ADB
- Security Install from unknown sources

Is it possible to do these steps using an updater-script within an update.zip?